# Run script through multiple Google sheet tabs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script which deletes columns of information that is now rendered obsolete.

However, I have multiple tabs which means going through them all manually, how can I edit my script to do this automatically for me, I have been trying for an hour or so now on Google trying other peoples solutions but because my coding skills is below basic I have no clue what I am doing.

```
function deleteColumns() {
  var required = ["Owned",  "Set",  "Card number",  "Edition",  "Rarity",   "Name", "Card type",];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var width = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues()[0];
  for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (required.indexOf(headers[i]) == -1) {
      sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Log 1]
[image: Log 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You need to make two modifications:

- Use [getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) to get all the sheets of your spreadsheet file.
- Define a list of sheet names you would like to execute your current solution to:

  `var selectedSheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet5","Test2"];`
- Create a for loop (in this case [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) and iterate over the sheets.
- Finally (optional), for every sheet check if the sheet name is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the `selectedSheets` array you defined earlier.

**Solution - Run on selected sheets:**

Adjust `selectedSheets` to include the sheet names for which you want to run the script. Make sure the names match exactly the name of your sheets. No extra spaces or different lower/upper case letters.

```
function deleteColumns() {
  var required = ["Owned",  "Set",  "Card number",  "Edition",  "Rarity",   "Name", "Card type",];
  var selectedSheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet5","Test2"]; // select the sheets you want to run the function for
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets
  // iterate over all sheets and execute code on selectedSheets
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{
     if(selectedSheets.includes(sheet.getName())){           
        var width = sheet.getLastColumn();
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues()[0];
        for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if (required.indexOf(headers[i]) == -1) {
           sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
        }
        }
     }
  });
}
```

**Solution - Run on every sheet in the spreadsheet:**

```
function deleteColumns() {
  var required = ["Owned",  "Set",  "Card number",  "Edition",  "Rarity",   "Name", "Card type",];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets
  // iterate over all sheets and execute code on selectedSheets
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{
        var width = sheet.getLastColumn();
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues()[0];
        for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if (required.indexOf(headers[i]) == -1) {
           sheet.deleteColumn(i+1);
        }
        }
  });
}
```

Comment: I used the script you had created and it is coming up with the error I was getting when I was trying to get it to work on my own: 'Attempted to execute deleteColumns, but could not save.'

Comment: I have included pictures on what I am running, and how I am running it as well as the errors that are coming up when I try to run. I am running in the google script editor and not as a macro in sheets. please see original post for pictures.

Comment: @Jesse is the script attached to a spreadsheet file or it is a standalone project? how did you go to the script editor ? via a spreadsheet or you created a new project?

Comment: the script is attached to the spreadsheet, and I went to the script editor via the spreadsheet: Tools> Script Editor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118348/discussion-between-marios-and-jesse).