# Clear cells script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

So I have a google sheet document which houses figured for each hour of the day from 6 - 16:00 (each hour in a different tab.

I’m looking to add a script and a button that will allow me to clear all the cells on all sheets with one click, I managed to find help online which would clear what sheet, but when I tried to add in the other sheet names it wouldn’t work (o really have no clue about script or coding so that is my issue)

Essentially I need f2:aa86 clearing from all of the hourly tabs which are named “7:00” “8:00” “9:00” etc

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi and welcome. A question... you said initially said _clear all the cells_ but later you refer to _f2:aa86 clearing_. What do you understand by the term `f2:aa86 clearing`?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to learn how to write scripts OR, at the very least, how to adapt an existing script to your own circumstances. This answer is designed to provide a solution by referencing some existing scripts and also helping with referencing more information.

- You want *a button that will allow me to clear all the cells on all sheets with one click*

  - The easiest solution might be to develop a custom menu; check [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)  for some script examples.
- You want to the script to work on all hourly tabs (6 - 16:00) which are named “7:00” “8:00” “9:00” etc_

  - The solution here is to list the specific sheet names; in [Run script through multiple Google sheet tabs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149989/196152) on webapps, the option to `Run on selected sheets` describes how to process only named sheets.
- You want to *clear all the cells* on each sheet. There's a command that does that: `clearContents()` and the documentation reference includes a code snippet  [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#clearcontents).

---

Putting this all together you might use these scripts:

---

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Clear sheets', 'clearSheets')
      .addToUi();
}

function clearSheets() {
  var selectedSheets = ["6:00","7:00","8:00","9:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"]; // select the sheets you want to run the function for
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets
  // iterate over all sheets and execute code on selectedSheets
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{
     if(selectedSheets.includes(sheet.getName())){
      sheet.clearContents()
      // Logger.log("Cleared contents - sheet:"+sheet.getName())
     }
  })
}
```